# Reorganize the data by months in grafana using psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

im trying to do a "AVG" by months but grafana wont let me do it because im using two Selects and the first one is using the other select and i can`t specifie my time column.
I want to get a "time series"(type of grafana dashboard) where it show´s me the average by month in grafana but i dont know how could i do it with psql and the code i have.

This is the code im using:

```
SELECT AVG(lol), NOW() as time FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ticket_id)), SUM(time_spent_minutes) AS "lol" 
FROM ticket_messages
WHERE admin_id IN ('20439', '20457', '20291', '20371', '20357', '20235','20449','20355','20488') 
GROUP BY ticket_id) as media
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the temporal column coming from? As of now your query is not doing anything specifically.

I would think that probably you have a `ticket_date` column available somewhere, the below query could become

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ticket_date) ticket_month, 
    SUM(time_spent_minutes)/COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id) avg_time 
FROM ticket_messages
WHERE 
    admin_id IN ('20439', '20457', '20291', '20371', '20357', '20235','20449','20355','20488') 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ticket_date)
```

Comment: Really thanks too you it work perfectly as i wanted.

Comment: Sorryto bother you again but could you tell me how can i do this code but just for 1 year spam

Comment: You just need to add a filter in the WHERE clause `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ticket_date) = 2022`

Comment: Could i do it using "updated_on BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 YEAR' AND NOW()" ?

Comment: yes of course, you know the data model

Comment: could you help me with something?